# Trying to getElementById from another one component

Tags: javascript, html, components

I need your help about a display issue I got using getElementbyId.
So, I'm using a function called 'Billing' (located in my component), that supposed to take in param 'billing-info' (**my id**).
In my component, I'm able to retrieve the param (billing-info), then I'm trying to display an html that contain this param (billing-info), but I got this error ' '*document.getElementById(element).style')*'
The html is not read and not displayed.

Please find below all details,
Let me know if you need more info.
Thank you in advance,
Matt

`allBills.view.js`

```
billing: function() {
   billingComponent.alert('billing-info');
}
```

`billingComponent.js`

```
 alert: function(element) {
    console.log('element', element);
    // 'billing-info' is print here
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    console.log('container', container);
    document.getElementById(element).style.display = "block";
  },


<div id='billing-info'>
  <h1>All bills goes here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I got this error ' 'document.getElementById(element).style')'

Comment: This doesn't look like an error

Comment: sorry this is the entire error I got, TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(element).style')

Comment: This means that the element couldn't be found in the DOM.

Comment: I also tried,   document.getElementById('billing-info').style.display = "block"; and still have the error

Comment: Yes I agree but I don't know why

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to add my html in billingComponent.js into my DOM in allBill.view.js

Comment: More info needed.  How are these components related, are both script files loaded by the same document or is something inside an iframe.

Comment: You could also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: No only the view is loaded... There is no chance that my id in my component can be read because when my function is called only the view is load. I'm trying to find a solution to read in both if possible...